Правка тест в jest
Создан отрисовка формы и необходимо сделать jest-тест


import { el, setChildren } from 'redom';
import Inputmask from 'inputmask';

export function drawingForm() {
  const formContainer = el('div.container');
  const formPayment = el('div.payment.payment__dots');

  const formLogo = el('div.logo#logo');
  const img = el('img');
  setChildren(formLogo, img);

  const form = el('form.form');
  const h2 = el('h2', 'Детали оплаты');

  const formCard = el('div.form__number.form__detail'),
    labelCard = el('label', 'Номер карты'),
    inputNumberCard = el('input#number', {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: '0000 0000 0000 0000',
    }),
    alertCard = el('div.alert#alert-2', 'Введите корректный номер карты');

  Inputmask('9999 9999 9999 9999').mask(inputNumberCard);

  setChildren(formCard, [labelCard, inputNumberCard, alertCard]);

  const formData = el('div.form__expiry.form__detail'),
    labelData = el('label', 'Дата  карты'),
    inputData = el('input#date', {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'ММ/ГГ',
    }),
    alertData = el(
      'div.alert#alert-3',
      'Введите корректную дату действия карты',
    );

  Inputmask('99/99').mask(inputData);
  setChildren(formData, [labelData, inputData, alertData]);

  const formCVC = el('div.form__cvv.form__detail'),
    labelCVC = el('label', 'CVC/CVV'),
    inputCVC = el('input#cvv', {
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: '000',
      maxlength: '4',
    }),
    alertCVC = el('div.alert#alert-4', 'Введите корректный CVC/CVV');
  setChildren(formCVC, [labelCVC, inputCVC, alertCVC]);

  const formEmail = el('div.form__email.form__detail'),
    labelEmail = el('label', 'E-mail'),
    inputEmail = el('input#email', {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Введите E-mail',
    }),
    alertEmail = el('div.alert#alert-5', 'Введите корректный E-mail');
  Inputmask('email').mask(inputEmail);
  setChildren(formEmail, [labelEmail, inputEmail, alertEmail]);

  const button = el('button.button ', 'Оплатить', { type: 'submit' });

  setChildren(form, [h2, formCard, formData, formCVC, formEmail, button]);
  setChildren(formPayment, [formLogo, form]);
  setChildren(formContainer, formPayment);

  setChildren(window.document.body, formContainer);

  return form, formCard, formData, formCVC, formEmail, button;
}



Но почему то вылетает ошибка при запуске теста, что указала не правильно?



test('Функция создания DOM-дерева должна вернуть DOM-элемент, в котором содержится строго четыре поля для ввода с плейсхолдерами «Номер карты», «ММ/ГГ», CVV/CVC, Email.', () => {
  const funс = drawingForm();
  expect(funс.form instanceof HTMLFormElement).toBeTruthy();
  expect(funс.form).toHaveLength(5);
  expect(funс.formCard).toHaveProperty('class', 'form__number form__detail');
  expect(funс.formData).toHaveProperty('class', 'form__expiry.form__detail');
  expect(funс.formCVC).toHaveProperty('class', 'form__cvv.form__detail');
  expect(funс.formEmail).toHaveProperty('class', 'form__email.form__detail');
});




Попробуйте return {form, formCard, formData, formCVC, formEmail, button};

спасибо @
Andrei Khotko, но все еще ошибка   `expect(received).toHaveProperty(path, value)
Expected path: "class"
Received path: []

Expected value: "form__number form__detail"
Received value: <div class="form__number form__detail"><label>Номер карты</label><input id="number" inputmode="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" type="text" /><div class="alert" id="alert-2">Введите корректный номер карты</div></div>`


Вы неправильно написали тесты для проверки имени класса элемента. Если позволит время, напишу ответ сегодня. Если нет, то кратко: el() возвращает объект Element. Там есть поле "className". Его и нужно проверять

Предыдущий мой комментарий - я не работал с библиотекой redom и не писал никогда тесты для HTML Element, так что это только мои догадки. Мне нужно попробовать у себя локально запустить и проверить, прежде чем дать ответ

@
Andrei Khotko спасибо большое, expect(funс.formCard).toHaveProperty('className', 'form__number form__detail'); так заработало
